# Getting newly created ID from Eloquent Model Event

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a model with a non auto-incrementing primary key `ID` which I have defined in my model.

```
protected $primaryKey = "ID";
```

In my AppServiceProvider, I have some model listeners.

```
Product::created(function ($product){
    dd($product);
});
```

So if I go to insert a new row:

```
$NewProduct = new Product;
$NewProduct->ID = 12345;
$NewProduct->Name = "Test";
```

The event is fired, so the `dd` gets run in the AppServiceProvider. The ID goes into the database as expected, but the `$product` array which I'm outputting shows the ID as 0.

Why is the ID showing as 0 when it went into the database as 12345?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should explicitly set the auto increment property as false to make it work. In your model:

```
protected $primaryKey = "ID";
public $incrementing = false;
```

> Primary Keys
>
> Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column
>   named id. You may define a $primaryKey property to override this
>   convention.
>
> In addition, Eloquent assumes that the primary key is an incrementing
>   integer value. If you wish to use a non-incrementing primary key, you
>   must set the $incrementing property on your model to false.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure but did you set incrementing to false in model?

```
public $incrementing = false;
```